# .htaccess file hide GET request in URL

Tags: .htaccess, url

I am very new to .htaccess files and may have done mine wrong. I have been gathering snippets of code trying to get done what I want.

This is what I have in my file so far

I read this should be in your .htaccess file

```
Options +MultiViews
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
```

This was added to force a redirect from HTTP to HTTPS

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This was added to remove .php at the end of all the files

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

This was added to remove the showing of /index when the home link was pressed

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*\/index?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php?$ "/$1" [R=301,L]
```

I have tried a lot of ideas I found on both here and other sites from Google. I have had no luck hiding the GET request. 
Currently, the URL looks like https://mysite.ca/event?id=123
What I would like it to look like is either https://mysite.ca/event/123

This is hosted on Godaddy and it is just a plain PHP site if that makes any difference.

Any ideas would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `Options +MultiViews` already removes .php extension so you don't need:

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]`

About your problem try this Rule:

`RewriteRule ^event/([0-9]+)?$ event?id=$1 [NC]`

Which changes url from `example.com/event/<number>` to `example.com/event?id=<number>`

Although, if your site makes infinite redirects then you should change it to:

`RewriteRule ^events/([0-9]+)?$ event?id=$1 [NC]`

This happens if you have some includes/headers that redirect back to event and creates infinite loop.

Comment: Thank you, I removed that extra code and you were right the Options +MulitViews removed the ,php for me. I tried your code and it didnt change anything, it keeps the url example.com/event?id=123

Comment: you are supposed to enter in browser: example.com/event/123 so it will internally redirect you to example.com/event?id=123 not the otherway around.

Comment: OK I get it thanks, is there a way so that when a link is clicked it shows it that way instead of typing it in that way?

Comment: What do you mean? Change all links (meaning href etc..) using the old url with the new url in your site and it will do its work...

Comment: so right now my href would be "event?id=123", should I change them to "event/123" it will still be recognized as a GET request?

Comment: Assuming you used the above RewriteUrl if you go to browser and enter your-domain.com/event/123 it will INTERNALLY (you wont see it) redirect you to your-domain.com/event?id=123 and thus will auto-make it a GET request.

Comment: Got it, Thanks!!